# Drupal function: content type

Tags: blocks, nodes

In my module I created a function called: functuion specialblocks_access. Right now the function allows a action only if the user created that content. However I want to specifiy the type of content (Example: access to Blog content but not Basic Page Content if conditions met). I have added: `if ($content->type=="blog"){ }` to the below code to specifiy blog content. However the code doesn't work. If I delete that line of code I just mention, it works but it allows all content. I want to specifiy the type of content.

Code:

```
function specialblocks_access($sOp, $sType = NULL, $iDelta = NULL) {
  //Users with administer hotblocks can do whatever they want

  if (user_access('administer specialblocks')) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  //This check determines whether the user can do any operations to a given block 
  //(not an item in the block, but to the block): assign, create, or order
   **if ($content->type=="blog")**{
  if (preg_match('#node/([0-9]+)#', $_GET['q'], $matches)) {
              if ($node = node_load($matches[1])) {
                global $user;
                if ($user->uid == $node->uid) {
  if($sOp == 'any block controls') {
    if (specialblocks_access('assign items to any specialblocks', NULL, $iDelta)) {
      return TRUE;
    }


}
}
}
**}**
```

Comment: According to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_content_form/7 : " It is impossible to define a content type without implementing hook_form()" So if I implement the hook_form in their example, how can the content type be defined in my function?

Comment: `$content` doesn't seem to have been defined anywhere, so you're accessing a property of a non-existent variable. I highly suggest you set `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your php.ini file (in PHP 5.4 or later) so that you get alerted when this sort of error occurs.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so. Any suggestions on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Well, how is this function being called? Is it a menu item access callback? (If so, the signature - the names of the parameter variables it's receiving - is quite funky.)